# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures version mismatch (asks for 3.0.0, but the latest version is 2.2.0)

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

I get this error when I'm building my ASP.NET Core MVC application:

> Error CS0012  The type 'Controller' is defined in an assembly that is
>   not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'

[image]

And when I go to NuGet site, I see that the latest version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures` is `2.2.0`.

What should I do?

Comment: Hmmm? I never get this kind of error when I am working with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem in my Class Library project. I found a solution by adding the following code to the project's .csproj file. I hope it works for you, too.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET Core applications should use the web SDK. If you create a new ASP.NET Core MVC project, then inspect the project file, you'll see it has `Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"`. If yours just says `Microsoft.NET.Sdk`, you might want to change it.

If you're not using the web SDK for a good reason (for example, your project is a class library, not an application/exe), then given that the version number it's complaining about, it's clear you're using .NET Core 3.0. In 3.0 and higher, framework libraries are no longer distributed as NuGet packages, but instead use a new versionless `FrameworkReference` MSBuild item. Once everything targets .NET Core 3.0 and higher a LOT of package versioning issues are going to disappear.

Anyway, the ASP.NET docs page has a [good example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#migrate-libraries-via-multi-targeting) on the page for migrating from 2.2 to 3.0. There's also [a little more information on `FrameworkReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#framework-reference).

Here's the example I like that shows the difference between 3.0 and earlier versions:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.0;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp3.0'">
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have probably updated a nuget or referenced something that causes the mismatch.

1. open your solution go to the project
2. check references -> Microsoft...ViewFeatures
3. right click check properties window, you should see version there
4. the problem can be that some dll requires a higher version of this package
5. consolidating/updating some nuget that delivers this package as well might help, the dll/package might have been put into another nuget instead of shipping it separately